# how to customise side indexer in android?

Tags: android

I am working on a project in android which has a listview with channel numbers 000 to 1000.I need to display a side indexer in the listview.i have achieved that with 0 to 9 but I want the side indexer to be displayed as 0,80,160,240,320 etc..I dont know how to customise mycode.I have posted my code also..

```
public class SideIndexerActivity extends Activity
{
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    // x and y coordinates within our side index
    private static float sideIndexX;
    private static float sideIndexY;

    // height of side index
    private int sideIndexHeight;

    // number of items in the side index
    private int indexListSize;

    // list with items for side index
    private ArrayList<Object[]> indexList = null;




    static String[] NUMBERS = new String[] { "000","001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010",
                                                 "011","012","013","014","015","016","017","018","019","020","021",
                                                 "022","023","024","025","026","027","028","029","030","100","101",
                                                 "102","104","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","200","201",
                                                 "202","203","204","204","205","206","207","208","209","210","300","301","302","303","304",
                                                 "304","305","306","407","408","509","610","600","701","702","803","903",
                                                 "804","805","906","907","708","809","1000","8000"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // don't forget to sort our array (in case it's not sorted)
        Arrays.sort(NUMBERS);

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NUMBERS));
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SideIndexGestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Object[]> createIndex(String[] strArr)
    {
        ArrayList<Object[]> tmpIndexList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;

        int tmpPos = 0;
        String tmpLetter = "";
        String currentLetter = null;
        String strItem = null;

        for (int j = 0; j < strArr.length; j++)
        {
            strItem = strArr[j];
            currentLetter = strItem.substring(0, 1);

            // every time new letters comes
            // save it to index list
            if (!currentLetter.equals(tmpLetter))
            {
                tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
                tmpIndexItem[0] = tmpLetter;
                tmpIndexItem[1] = tmpPos - 1;
                tmpIndexItem[2] = j - 1;

                tmpLetter = currentLetter;
                tmpPos = j + 1;

                tmpIndexList.add(tmpIndexItem);
            }
        }

        // save also last letter
        tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
        tmpIndexItem[0] = tmpLetter;
        tmpIndexItem[1] = tmpPos - 1;
        tmpIndexItem[2] = strArr.length - 1;
        tmpIndexList.add(tmpIndexItem);

        // and remove first temporary empty entry
        if (tmpIndexList != null && tmpIndexList.size() > 0)
        {
            tmpIndexList.remove(0);
        }

        return tmpIndexList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        LinearLayout sideIndex = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
        sideIndexHeight = sideIndex.getHeight();
        sideIndex.removeAllViews();

        // TextView for every visible item
        TextView tmpTV = null;

        // we'll create the index list
        indexList = createIndex(NUMBERS );

        // number of items in the index List
        indexListSize = indexList.size();

        // maximal number of item, which could be displayed
        int indexMaxSize = (int) Math.floor(sideIndex.getHeight() / 20);

        int tmpIndexListSize = indexListSize;

        // handling that case when indexListSize > indexMaxSize
        while (tmpIndexListSize > indexMaxSize)
        {
            tmpIndexListSize = tmpIndexListSize / 2;
        }

        // computing delta (only a part of items will be displayed to save a
        // place)
        double delta = indexListSize / tmpIndexListSize;

        String tmpLetter = null;
        Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;

        // show every m-th letter
        for (double i = 1; i <= indexListSize; i = i+ delta)
        {
            tmpIndexItem = indexList.get((int) i - 1);
            tmpLetter = tmpIndexItem[0].toString();
            tmpTV = new TextView(this);
            tmpTV.setText(tmpLetter);
            tmpTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tmpTV.setTextSize(20);
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
            tmpTV.setLayoutParams(params);
            sideIndex.addView(tmpTV);
        }

        // and set a touch listener for it
        sideIndex.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                // now you know coordinates of touch
                sideIndexX = event.getX();
                sideIndexY = event.getY();

                // and can display a proper item it country list
                displayListItem();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    class SideIndexGestureListener extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            // we know already coordinates of first touch
            // we know as well a scroll distance
            sideIndexX = sideIndexX - distanceX;
            sideIndexY = sideIndexY - distanceY;

            // when the user scrolls within our side index
            // we can show for every position in it a proper
            // item in the country list
            if (sideIndexX >= 0 && sideIndexY >= 0)
            {
                displayListItem();
            }

            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }
    }

    public void displayListItem()
    {
        // compute number of pixels for every side index item
        double pixelPerIndexItem = (double) sideIndexHeight / indexListSize;

        // compute the item index for given event position belongs to
        int itemPosition = (int) (sideIndexY / pixelPerIndexItem);

        // compute minimal position for the item in the list
        int minPosition = (int) (itemPosition * pixelPerIndexItem);

        // get the item (we can do it since we know item index)
        Object[] indexItem = indexList.get(itemPosition);

        // and compute the proper item in the country list
        int indexMin = Integer.parseInt(indexItem[1].toString());
        int indexMax = Integer.parseInt(indexItem[2].toString());
        int indexDelta = Math.max(1, indexMax - indexMin);

        double pixelPerSubitem = pixelPerIndexItem / indexDelta;
        int subitemPosition = (int) (indexMin + (sideIndexY - minPosition) / pixelPerSubitem);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        listView.setSelection(subitemPosition);
    }
}
```

Pls help me with some ideas.

now my listview is displayed as side index

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

but I want as 
0
80
160
240
320
400
480
640
720
800
880

pls help..

Comment: Change your array to have the values you want to display?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
currentLetter = strItem.substring(0, 1);
```

to

```
currentLetter = strItem.substring(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code does the work anywhere for the output you are looking for.

Can you tell your problem exactly and the code relevent to it.

The numbers you have added in [] is "001, 002... and you want results as 0, 80, ... I mean I don't see any calculations or selection relvant to your needs in the code.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer